Decoding a Text File found inside a apk
I recently just exploring an apk file just by unziping it and found a ad-blocking.txt file in /assests directory. It has some wired character in it which can't be read by vscode. I just want to know is it some type of file format it is.
I tried some compression formats.Using Hex editor to open it.I also used some decompiler too.I also searched on internet for what type of packing does apk use to pack txt file.But I can't find anything. And there were other files like json file which are very normal.I am just curious to read it like other ad-blocking.txt out there.I will link the Text file here.
